# JFrame graphics flashing

Tags: java

I am trying to make a information JFrame on loading, after load the new frame will open up with the game I am creating, the only problem is that my loading time keeps flashing, I know basic java, but I'm not super advanced, here is my code:

```
package Console;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Main extends Canvas implements Runnable{

public boolean running = false;
public boolean LoadingScreen = false;
public Thread mainThread;
public Thread loadThread;
public boolean finishedLoading = false;

public void start_loading()
{




}

public void stop_loading()
{

    if(!LoadingScreen)
    {

        return;

    }else
    {

        LoadingScreen = false;
        try {
            loadThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public synchronized void start()
{

    if(LoadingScreen)
    {

        return;

    }else
    {

        LoadingScreen = true;
        loadThread = new Thread(this);
        loadThread.start();

    }

    if(running == true)
    {

        return;

    }else
    {

        running = true;
        mainThread = new Thread(this);
        mainThread.start();

    }

}

public synchronized void stop()
{

    if(!running)
    {

        return;

    }else
    {

        running = false;
        try 
        {

            mainThread.join();

        }
        catch 
        (InterruptedException e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}

public static final int WIDTH = 240, HEIGHT = 260, SCALE = 2;
//public static JTextArea loadingShow = new JTextArea();

public static void main(String args[])
{

    Main Main = new Main();
    Main.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    Main.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    Main.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

    JFrame screen = new JFrame("Screen");
    screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    screen.setSize(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);
    screen.setResizable(false);
    //screen.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));
    screen.add(Main);
    //JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    //text.setText("Starting up game...\n---------------------------------------\nCredits:\nCreated by Illurity.\n");

    //text.setEditable(false);
    //loadingShow.setEditable(false);
    //screen.add(loadingShow);
    //screen.add(text);
    screen.setVisible(true);

    Main.start();

}

public static int LoadTime = 0;


public void run() 
{

    //Game Loop
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double amountOfTicks = 60D;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;

    while(running == true)
    {

        //Loading
        while(LoadingScreen == true)
        {

            while(LoadTime < 10000)
            {

                render();
                LoadTime += 2;

            }

            finishedLoading = true;
            System.out.println("FInished Loading");
            stop_loading();
            start();

        }
        //End loading
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        if(delta >= 1)
        {

            tick();
            delta--;
            //number++;
            System.out.println("Running");

        }

        render();

    }

    stop();

}

public void tick()
{} 

public void render()
{

    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null)
    {

        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;

    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();


    int fontSize = 16;

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);

    g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, fontSize));

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    g.drawString("Load: ", 1, 15);
    g.drawString(Integer.toString(LoadTime / 100), 17, 15);

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();

}

}
```

Have I made some sort of obvious mistake?

Comment: Cut down the number of threads you are using.  There should only be a single thread used for rendering and it should only ever render the current state.  You need to `yield` or `sleep` within the "loading" section to allow the UI time to be repainted.  You keep creating thread's that wrap around the same `Runnable`, but none of those threads actually ever exit, not until `running` becomes false.  Be careful with using `return` within in the middle of methods, best practices suggest that your method should have a single entry and exit point, it makes it easier to determine the logic flow...

Comment: Why are you mixing AWT (Canvas) with Swing (JFrame and everything else)?

Comment: You'll want to make use of `volatile` or `AtomicBoolean` for your flags, so that their actual values are evaluated between the threads...

Comment: You seriously need to take some time to understand how threading works.  You also need to understand how a rendering loop is suppose to work.  You are suppose to be injecting a delay of `n` number of milliseconds between each frame so you can maintain a steady frame rate, not just dumping everything as fast as you can...

Comment: You main loop should do something like, update game state, render game state, calculate the time it took to update and render the current state, calculate the amount of time the loop will need to sleep in order to maintain the current frame rate (`optimialFrameRateTime - amountOfTimeToUpdateState`), then sleep and repeat...It should have no other logic in it nor should it be making decisions about what should or how it should be rendered...

Comment: Like I said I know some basic java but this is the challenge I am trying to overcome and hoping to learn new things, I am currently just trying to use what I know, and I realise it is becoming a mess. If there is anything anyone knows that would assist me in understand what I need to know to fix this mess, please send me a link or tell me here. Thank you for the tips everyone, but I do not know how to cut down the number of threads, I have always had trouble with threading, and I do not know how to properly do the game loop. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The MAIN cause of your problem is the two threads you are running.  Get rid of the "loading" thread and do that ALL within the main thread.

Comment: You may also consider having a look at [Game Development StackExchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)